# TSQL Datediff from a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a simple query that I am trying to use this select statement on.

I am trying to get the difference in seconds from the date provided (a UNIX timestamp).

```
select 
   DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', CAST(CAST('2014-08-27 08:59:56.0000000' AS DATETIME) AS INT))
```

When I try this, I get the following error :

> Conversion failed when converting date and or time from character string.

I figured casting the string as `datetime` would have resolved that?

Comment: Could you tell whether '19700101' is in fact the date 01 January of 1970? Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should try to avoid using shorthands for the datepart, instead of `s`, use `SECOND`. 
Another good practice when casting a string to a date is to use `CONVERT` so you can specify the format to use on the conversion (in your case, it would be `121`. Finally, for the whole thing to work, you'll need to use less miliseconds (up to 3):

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(50)
SET @Date = '2014-08-27 08:59:56.0000000'

SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,'19700101',CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@Date,23),121))
```